# Trying to only select if it meets a criteria

Tags: mysql, if-statement, nested

I am trying to narrow down my results and group them. below is my query.  It brings all the attendees that checked in for the specific session name.

These are the results now

```
-------|---|------------------|----------------|----|
Person1 One SKA - Monday Aft    SK Team          1
Person1 One SKA - Monday Eve    Commander Dana   1
Person1 One SKA - Monday Morn   Commander Linda  1
Person2 Two SKA - Monday Aft    SK Team          1
Person2 Two SKA - Monday Morn   Commander Linda  1
```

What I am trying to do is to narrow down the results where it brings in only whoever attended all three sessions?  For example, in this scenario, Person 1 attended all three but not person 2.

```
SELECT ea.first_name, ea.last_name, es.name, es.keynote_speaker,
        count(esc.id = ea.id  ) as Times_Checked_In
FROM event e
JOIN  event_session es ON e.id =  es.event_id
JOIN event_session_checkin esc on es.id = esc.event_session_id
JOIN event_attendee ea ON esc.event_attendee_id = ea.id
WHERE  e.external_id='2019SWBC' and es.name like 'SKA - M%'
group by ea.id, es.name,es.keynote_speaker, ea.first_name, 
ea.last_name
order by ea.id desc;
```

Any ninja Mysql expert that can help me

also, how can i edit the column 1 so that instead of display the #1, it displays a default of a string of 'Yes'?  so that way i can name that column as "atteneded all?"  and say 'yes'

Comment: Have you looked into the `having` clause?

Comment: @Someguywhocodes can you expand on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, just add the HAVING clause after group to do the filtering:

```
SELECT ea.first_name, ea.last_name, es.name, es.keynote_speaker,
        count(*) as Times_Checked_In
FROM event e
JOIN  event_session es ON e.id =  es.event_id
JOIN event_session_checkin esc on es.id = esc.event_session_id
JOIN event_attendee ea ON esc.event_attendee_id = ea.id
WHERE  e.external_id='2019SWBC' and es.name like 'SKA - M%'
group by ea.id, es.name,es.keynote_speaker, ea.first_name, 
ea.last_name
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
order by ea.id desc;
```

Comment: Awesome, how can i make the one a yes instead of a 1?

Comment: Sorry , not sure what you meant by "make the one a yes instead of a 1". Can you provide more details?

Comment: Yes.  I am going to edit my original question so i can have more room.

Comment: You can use CASE in your query: CASE WHEN columName=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END